# Inconsistency date value when read.xlsx in R

Tags: r, date

I am using the read.xlsx function in R to read excel sheets. All the values of a date column 'A' is of the form dd/mm/yyyy. However,when using the read.xlsx function, the values of the date parsed ranges from being an integer ie. 42283 to string i.e. 20/08/2015. This probelm persist even when I uses read.xlsx2.

I guess the inconsistency in the format for different rows makes it hard to change the column to a single standard format. Also, it is hard to specify the column classes in the read.xlsx since I have more than 100 variables.

Are there ways around this problem and also is this an excel specific problems?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem with date formats is pervasive and it seems like every R package out there deals with it differently. My experience with `read.xlsx` has been that it sometimes saves the date as a character string of numbers, e.g. "42438" as character data that I then have to convert to numeric and then to POSIXct. Then other times, it seems to save it as numeric and sometimes as character and once in a while, actually as POSIXct! If you're consistently getting character data in the form "20/08/2015", try the `lubridate` package:

```
 library(lubridate)
 dmy("20/08/2015")
```